# How To apply display: none; to a class in a div

Tags: css, css-selectors, display

I'm trying to hide some of the `<div class="form-group">` rows in this group of rows. I'd like to hide Boolean 1 and Boolean 3. Can I apply `display: none;` on the subrecord-form-fields somehow to hide just some of the rows?

```
<div class="subrecord-form-fields">
      <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="resource_user_defined__boolean_1_" contextual="resource">Boolean 1</label><div class="col-sm-1 checkbox"><input id="resource_user_defined__boolean_1_" type="checkbox" name="resource[user_defined][boolean_1]" value="1" label_opts="{:contextual=>&quot;resource&quot;}" col_size="1" controls_class="checkbox"></div></div>
      <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="resource_user_defined__boolean_2_" contextual="resource">Boolean 2</label><div class="col-sm-1 checkbox"><input id="resource_user_defined__boolean_2_" type="checkbox" name="resource[user_defined][boolean_2]" value="1" label_opts="{:contextual=>&quot;resource&quot;}" col_size="1" controls_class="checkbox"></div></div>
      <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="resource_user_defined__boolean_3_" contextual="resource">Boolean 3</label><div class="col-sm-1 checkbox"><input id="resource_user_defined__boolean_3_" type="checkbox" name="resource[user_defined][boolean_3]" value="1" label_opts="{:contextual=>&quot;resource&quot;}" col_size="1" controls_class="checkbox"></div></div>
      <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="resource_user_defined__integer_1_" contextual="resource">Integer 1</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input id="resource_user_defined__integer_1_" type="text" value="" name="resource[user_defined][integer_1]" class="form-control"></div></div>
```

Update: Sorry, should've mentioned that I'm not 100% sure this list will never change, so I'd like to be able to single out rows by name, not just the 2nd row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will hide all labels with `for` attribute ending in `__boolean_3_` or `__boolean_1_` and also any elements with ids ending in those strings (useful for cases where they are generated in random order).

```css
[for$="__boolean_3_"],
[for$="__boolean_1_"],
[id$="__boolean_3_"],
[id$="__boolean_1_"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```css
[for$="__boolean_3_"],
[for$="__boolean_1_"],
[id$="__boolean_3_"],
[id$="__boolean_1_"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="subrecord-form-fields">
  <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="resource_user_defined__boolean_1_" contextual="resource">Boolean 1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-1 checkbox"><input id="resource_user_defined__boolean_1_" type="checkbox" name="resource[user_defined][boolean_1]" value="1" label_opts="{:contextual=>&quot;resource&quot;}" col_size="1" controls_class="checkbox"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="resource_user_defined__boolean_2_" contextual="resource">Boolean 2</label>
    <div class="col-sm-1 checkbox"><input id="resource_user_defined__boolean_2_" type="checkbox" name="resource[user_defined][boolean_2]" value="1" label_opts="{:contextual=>&quot;resource&quot;}" col_size="1" controls_class="checkbox"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="resource_user_defined__boolean_3_" contextual="resource">Boolean 3</label>
    <div class="col-sm-1 checkbox"><input id="resource_user_defined__boolean_3_" type="checkbox" name="resource[user_defined][boolean_3]" value="1" label_opts="{:contextual=>&quot;resource&quot;}" col_size="1" controls_class="checkbox"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="resource_user_defined__integer_1_" contextual="resource">Integer 1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9"><input id="resource_user_defined__integer_1_" type="text" value="" name="resource[user_defined][integer_1]" class="form-control"></div>
  </div>
```

Obviously, if you know their order, `:nth-child()` comes in quite handy.
If you want to be more specific (to avoid false positives, you could prefix with `.subrecord-form-fields` or apply tags (i.e: `label[for$="__boolean_3_"]`, etc...).

But really, JS is the proper way to go here. If you want to have some fun, check out a full list of [CSS selectors, modifiers and combinators](https://www.quackit.com/css/selectors/).

Comment: Thanks! I'm thinking this is probably the way to go for what I need. I'm not 100% sure that this list will never change, so the `nth-child` way seems not quite as good as this one.

Comment: When I tried to add this using a .js file I'm getting an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"  I'm not sure what I need to do to actually use this.

Comment: FYI @Blake, the snippet in answer doesn't use any javascript but an `HTML` and `CSS` one

Comment: @Blake, that's not what I meant when I said *"JS is the proper way to go here"*. I didn't give you a JS answer. JS allows you to manipulate (change) HTML and CSS with ease. Rather than using over-complicated CSS selectors, one can achieve what they want/need with JS. For example: using JS, you could only target the labels, and delete/hide their parents, no longer having to worry about how to target the rest of `<label>` siblings. JS is more powerful and more flexible. Your request is almost too complex for CSS and quite trivial with JS, hence my remark in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! With the pseudo-class [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) you can do something like:

```
.subrecord-form-fields div:nth-child(1), .subrecord-form-fields div:nth-child(3)
{
    display: none;
}
```

I made a snippet for you, on how it could look like, now you need to play with some js to hide or show whenever you want.

```css
.subrecord-form-fields div:nth-child(1), .subrecord-form-fields div:nth-child(3)
{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="subrecord-form-fields">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="resource_user_defined__boolean_1_" contextual="resource">
    Boolean 1
   </label>
  <div class="col-sm-1 checkbox">
  <input id="resource_user_defined__boolean_1_" type="checkbox" name="resource[user_defined][boolean_1]" value="1" label_opts="{:contextual=>&quot;resource&quot;}" col_size="1" controls_class="checkbox"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="resource_user_defined__boolean_2_" contextual="resource">
    Boolean 2
   </label>
   <div class="col-sm-1 checkbox">
    <input id="resource_user_defined__boolean_2_" type="checkbox" name="resource[user_defined][boolean_2]" value="1" label_opts="{:contextual=>&quot;resource&quot;}" col_size="1" controls_class="checkbox">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="resource_user_defined__boolean_3_" contextual="resource">
    Boolean 3
   </label>
  <div class="col-sm-1 checkbox">
   <input id="resource_user_defined__boolean_3_" type="checkbox" name="resource[user_defined][boolean_3]" value="1" label_opts="{:contextual=>&quot;resource&quot;}" col_size="1" controls_class="checkbox">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="resource_user_defined__integer_1_" contextual="resource">
   Integer 1
  </label> 
 <div class="col-sm-9">
  <input id="resource_user_defined__integer_1_" type="text" value="" name="resource[user_defined][integer_1]" class="form-control">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that will work, though now that I see this,  I'm a bit afraid of the rows changing. I'm not 100% these things never change, or will never change.

Answer (score 1):

For example, to hide the 2nd `div` use this:

```
.subrecord-form-fields :nth-child(2)
{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to intercalate rows you can achieve that by doing this...

```
.subrecord-form-fields > :nth-child(2n -1)
{
    display: none;
}
```